# How can I examine a process' image?

Tags: linux, loader, hexdump, gcore

First I find the process' pid with `ps`:

```
% ps -a | grep 'a.out'
```

output:

```
36296 pts/0    00:00:07 a.out
```

Then I get an image of this process with `gcore`:

```
% sudo gcore 36296
```

output:

```
0x0000558eab27d131 in main ()
warning: Memory read failed for corefile section, 4096 bytes at 0xffffffffff600000.
Saved corefile core.36296
[Inferior 1 (process 36296) detached]
```

Then, hex dump object:

```
% hd core.36296 | grep 'HOME'
```

output:

```
001f4a90  3d 32 00 48 4f 4d 45 3d  2f 68 6f 6d 65 2f 63 61  |=2.HOME=/home/ca|
```

Now, I'm trying to find the section where environment variables is loaded. How can I do this ?

Comment: You would normally use a debugger to examine the core file.

Comment: The debugger would use the symbol table from the executable. If you don't want to use a debugger, you'll need to do the same thing yourself.

Comment: Is your question answered? Why no response?

Answer (score 2):

You should use a debugger!

For linux, gcc and gdb you can do:

```
> gdb <executable> <core-file>
```

Within gdb you now can examine the environment from the core file:

```
 (gdb) print ((char**)__environ)[0]
$1 = 0x7ffc6aba0a58 "SHELL=/bin/bash"
(gdb) print ((char**)__environ)[1]
$2 = 0x7ffc6aba0a68 "SESSION_MANAGER=local/unix:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1873,unix/unix:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1873"
```

unless you get a string with length 0.

If you do not have an executable with debug infos, you also can try to find the text with:

`strings –a <core-file>`

But before you write a core file and try to search  in it, you simply can get the environment from a process by using `ps` if your program is still running:

`ps eww <pid>`

Comment: I tried this steps and I still haven't found which segment these variables are placed in. Can you explain it step by step?

Comment: @CanDeniz: What have YOU tried? simply do "ps eww <pid>" and you got all your informations. Even so if running from core file with debugger and executable. Simply searching through all the strings with "string" command did not point you to anything. If you do that, you simply have to search.